# Rotate camera around scene with scrolling opengl ES

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, touch-event

I am trying to rotate the camera around the scene using touch (scroll):

```
public class SurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView 
        implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    SceneRenderer renderer;        

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                      float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        renderer.setMotion(distanceX, distanceY); // pass movement to render
        return true;
    }    
}
```

The camera moves in the render as follows:

```
public class SceneRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private float[] viewMatrix = new float[16];
    
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 3f,
        0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    ...
    // movement of camera
    public synchronized void setMotion(float xDistance, float yDistance) {
        Matrix.rotateM(viewMatrix, 0, -xDistance * 0.1f, 0, 1, 0);
        Matrix.rotateM(viewMatrix, 0, -yDistance * 0.1f, 1, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

This works well at first. But then the camera starts to rotate not as expected. How can I make the camera move correctly relative to the center of the scene (object) using scrolling? Maybe someone solved a similar problem?

Thank you for any answer/comment!

Workaround solution:

```
  private float kx = 0f;
  private float ky = 0f;
  private float radius = 3.0f;
  private float x, y, z = 0f;

  ...
  public synchronized void setMotion(float xDistance, float yDistance) {
      kx = kx + xDistance * 0.001f;
      x = (float) (radius * Math.sin(kx));
      z = (float) (radius * Math.cos(kx));

      ky = ky + yDistance * 0.001f;
      y = (float) (radius * Math.sin(ky));

      Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, x, -y, z, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  }
```

But with this approach, the camera moves away from the scene when rotating along the Y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In matrix algebra, order does matter. Since incremental rotations interleave matrices and break order, it won't work as you expect. Thus you need to rebuild the view-matrix based on cumulative delta x/y on every setMotion() call so that rotations would always be applied in right order as follows.

```
public class SceneRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private float[] viewMatrix = new float[16];
    private float cumulativeX = 0.0f;
    private float cumulativeY = 0.0f;

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 3f,
        0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        cumulativeX = 0.0f;
        cumulativeY = 0.0f;
    }

    ...
    // movement of camera
    public synchronized void setMotion(float xDistance, float yDistance) {

        cumulativeX += xDistance;
        cumulativeY += yDistance;

        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 3f,
            0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        //Matrix.rotateM(viewMatrix, 0, -cumulativeX * 0.1f, 0, 1, 0);
        //Matrix.rotateM(viewMatrix, 0, -cumulativeY * 0.1f, 1, 0, 0);

        Matrix.rotateM(viewMatrix, 0, -cumulativeY * 0.1f, 1, 0, 0);
        Matrix.rotateM(viewMatrix, 0, -cumulativeX * 0.1f, 0, 1, 0);
    }
}
```

### Appendix: Composing view-matrix only by setLookAtM

It's surely possible to achieve the same only with setLookAtM. To keep view-point in constant distance, move the view-point in [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). And  adjust up-direction too.

```
public synchronized void setMotion(float xDistance, float yDistance) {

    kx = kx + xDistance * 0.001f;
    ky = ky + yDistance * 0.001f;
    
    x = (float) (radius * Math.cos(ky) * Math.sin(kx));
    z = (float) (radius * Math.cos(ky) * Math.cos(kx));
    y = (float) (radius * Math.sin(ky));


    float[] up =
    {
        (float) (Math.sin(ky) * Math.sin(kx)),
        (float) (Math.cos(ky)),
        (float) (Math.sin(ky) * Math.cos(kx)),
    };
    Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0,
            x, -y, z,
            0f, 0f, 0f,
            up[0], up[1], up[2]
    );

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But the problem is that after the initial rotation, the scene starts to rotate along other axes. I added self-solution to the post, but it makes the camera move away from the scene when rotating along the Y axis. Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: According to your workaround solution, the order of rotations should have been X-axis > Y-axis. I updated the answer as such anyway. If you'd like to go with the setLookAtM solution, see the appendix. Thank you.